Ubuntu 24.04 installation freezes after the first reboot?
I get through the first part of the install of 24.04. At the point where the system reboots and instructs me to remove the installation media and press ENTER (which I do), the system begins to come up; I see the Ubuntu logo and the rotating busy icon for a short time, then that disappears completely. I have waited at least 30 minutes to see whether something happens, but nothing happens. I have tried this several times with the exact same response.
This is a Dell Latitude 7490 laptop with 256GB SSD and 8GB RAM. I have successfully installed 24.04 on several other similar laptops.
Does anyone have a clue what might be happening?
